# Can I access all the webcontrols in an aspx page somehow?

Tags: asp.net, fonts, web-controls

I need to change the font style and sizes of all the webcontrols in an aspx page, but there is so much of them, I don't want to do it one by one. I am using a CSS file, but it only affects simple text on the page and not the webcontrols. 
How can I access all the webcontrols at once?

Comment: You should still use css for that. There might be styles overriding your current css, and these you should edit. Please do not traverse the whole control tree and set inline styles, this will be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: _"I am using a CSS file, but it only affects simple text on the page and not the webcontrols"_ No, it affects all controls since all webcontrols are rendered as HTML controls. Of course you need to assign the [`CssClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Can you tell me more about it? Where do I have to assign it exactly?

Comment: @kisbovan93: i have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am using a CSS file, but it only affects simple text on the page
>   and not the webcontrols"

No, it affects all controls since all webcontrols are rendered as HTML controls. Of course you need to assign the [`CssClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can use codebehind or on aspx.

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass="MyCssClass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserName.CssClass = "MyCssClass";
}
```

If you use container controls like `Panel` you can apply the CSS on that and all children inherit those styles. So there is no need to assign the same class on every control.

Comment: Okay, so I have this so far:

I added a panel:
<asp:Panel ID="MainPanel" CssClass="MainStyleCssClass" runat="server">

Code behind:
MainPanel.CssClass = "MainStyleCssClass";

Css file:
.MainStyleCssClass
{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

Still doesnt work.

Comment: If you already aplply the `CssClass` on aspx you don't need to also assign it in codebehind. I just wanted to show both ways, programmatically or declaratively. Now, all controls sitting in the `Panel` inherit the class(most styles, not all).

Comment: I deleted my code from code behind, but still it only works if I add the font type to the webcontrol individually.

Comment: @kisbovan93: show the css-class. The [font-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) is inherited.